# Running php artisan migrate returns error from sqlite: "no such table: pragma_compile_options"

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-breeze

I was following this Laravel bootcamp:

https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/installation

I installed Laravel and changed DB_CONNECTION to sqlite as directed.

However when I tried to complete the installation of Laravel Breeze by running migrations, I received an exception from sqlite.

Here is the output from the command:

```
$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: pragma_compile_options (Connection: sqlite, SQL: select exists (select 1 from pragma_compile_options where compile_options = 'ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB') as enabled)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:822
    818▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    819▕                 );
    820▕             }
    821▕
  ➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
    823▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    824▕             );
    825▕         }
    826▕     }

      +30 vendor frames

  31  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

The file `database/database.sqlite` is created but is empty.

I tried to google the error message but nothing turned up.

Here is the sqlite version used:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.32.3 2020-06-18 14:00:33 7ebdfa80be8e8e73324b8d66b3460222eb74c7e9dfd655b48d6ca7e1933cc8fd
```

Here is the version of Laravel used:

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 10.34.2
```

Is there something I can do to continue the tutorial using sqlite as the database?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

It seems `pragma_compile_options` is a built-in table of `SQLite`.

Meaning, you not having such table means that, your Laravel's DB connection is configured for `SQLite` engine, but your actual database engine is something else.

- If that's the cause, fix your configs to use right engine, maybe try `MySQL`.

Another possible cause; maybe Laravel does not support your `SQLite` version.

- If that's the cause, try upgrading Laravel and/or downgrading SQLite.

##### Example configs

In my `./config/database.php` file, I have something like:

```
return [
    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        // ...
    ],
    
    // ...
];
```

### Old answer

Try dropping/removing all tables:

```
php artisan db:wipe
```

Then repeat:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Finally ensure DB has initial data, like:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Done!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how Laravel's DB connection can be configured for SQLite engine, but the actual database engine can be something else?  As well as how to "fix your configs to use the right engine"?

DB_CONNECTION was changed to sqlite in the .env file, and beyond that this is a vanilla installation of Laravel.

Comment: @JonathanMontgomery I added "Another possible cause", see if that helps, also, I added my configs as example.